# Rotate ImageView source from layout xml file

Tags: android, layout, rotation, imageview

I have this ImageView in my layout:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_divider"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield" />
```

It's a horizontal divider. I want to rotate it 90 degrees so I have a vertical divider.
 
Is there any possible way to do it right here from the layout and not the Activity class?

Comment: you can just set the height to `layout_height="fill_parent"` and then it'll be stretched all over the layout

Comment: Kindly accept/upVote the answer if you have got your solution :)

Comment: @thepoosh: The source image is not a square. It's a wide rectangle and doing what you say, will result in a thin vertical rectangle.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

You can use Available Since **API Level 11**

```
android:rotation="90"
```

Final Code to Put,

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_divider"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is no such attribute for ImageView, at least in mine! http://s15.postimage.org/gpit1dvrd/Untitled.png

Comment: @Mehran Visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:rotation For More Information

Comment: I disagree: android:roation attribute is only available since API 11: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#rotation

Comment: @Jeje You can visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:rotation For more details link which you have shared is incorrect in this context. :)

Comment: Sure, but then, follow the link: "This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol rotation."

Comment: @MehranMahmoudi Check for version you are developing on, See my updated answer

Comment: @Rinkalkumar I changed the target API from 10 to 15 in my project configurations, and android:rotation showed up. So there is no any other possible way for API 10?

Comment: @MehranMahmoudi There is no way you can rotate programmatically in API 10, One thing you can do is you can have two image one with 90 Degree rotation and one is default, :)

Comment: @Pankaj It starts working from  API Level 11 whats the device and OS you are using?

Comment: thanks,Now it works. I was expecting rotation would reflect in xml, but after running my project it gets rotated!!

Comment: Please note that the rotation is in Clockwise.

Comment: how can I rotate with one end being fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Add "id" at ImageView (if not generate auto):

```
 android:id="@+id/imageView"
```

and use the "id" (kotlin example):

```
val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
imageView.setRotation(90f) // rotate 90 degree
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in your code by creating a new bitmap object.
Check this out : http://android-er.blogspot.fr/2010/07/rotate-bitmap-image-using-matrix.html
And specifically this function

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(curScale, curScale);
matrix.postRotate(curRotate);

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, matrix, true);
myImageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
```