# Splash Image is being displayed horizontal and not vertical

Tags: android

I am making an image with my s4 Samsung device which I am trying to put as splash image for my app but I am facing problem that the image is being displayed horizontal and not vertical when I run the app on the device. At first, I put the image in the `drawable-hdpi` directory and later in `drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi` directories but I am getting the same result.

How can I fix it?

**xml file**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:background= "@drawable/splash_background"
    >

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout it's for oriented children not for background image. This post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243314/rotate-imageview-source-from-layout-xml-file)

can help you

Answer (score 0):

please **change the orientation of your image** using photoshop/paint or any other image editing software. then replace it with the old image.

**Note:**
   android:orientation="vertical"

is not to change/ rotate the screen!!
`orientation` property of `LinearLayout` is defining the alignment of its child components. That means, if you add an `ImageView` and a `TextView`, the `TextView` will be added after the `ImageView`. Components will be added vertically.

If you need to change the orientation you go through [layout for different screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html#create-layouts).

and, the drawable-hdpi, mdpi, xxhdpi etc.. are to keep images depending on the device. The device will render images from any of the folder depending on its screen resolution. please read the above link at developer site, it is clear.

Comment: I have changed the rotation with paint but no seccuss.

Comment: did u replaced it with all images in all of your drawable folders?

Comment: Yes I did. Additionally, the image had vertical orientation before on the desktop before I changed its orientation to horizental to try your answer..

Comment: can you share the image?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout       
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_draw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```